# Difference between "load static from staticfiles" and "django.core.context_processors.static" in Django

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, static-files

As I am learning about how Django handles static files, I have seen two different ways of serving static files while still allowing portability.

- One way is to do the following in the template:

  ```
  {% load static from staticfiles %}
  <img src="{% static "images/hi.jpg" %}" alt="Hi!" />
  ```

  as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static) on the Django docs.
- The other way I see is to load the context processor for static files, and then use

  ```
  <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/hi.jpg" alt="Hi!" />
  ```

  as noted [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-static) on the Django docs. When using this method, I change `STATIC_URL` based on

  ```
  if DEBUG:
       STATIC_URL = 'localhost'
  else:
       STATIC_URL = 'some_static_server_url'
  ```

Which is considered better practice?  Is one way better than the other?  For example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013436/django-referencing-static-files-in-templates) SO question has both methods as answers, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632232/static-files-in-django) has the second method. Any insights would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both methods are essentially the same when using Django's default `StaticFilesStorage`. Both methods are ignorant of any actual files. Both methods just join together the `STATIC_URL` setting and the actual file path.

There can be a difference when using a custom file storage backend. If you need flexibility, e.g. if some files are stored with different static urls, you can override the backend's `url` method to return an url based on the actual location of the file. That won't be possible using the `STATIC_URL` setting. However, this situation is quite rare: most servers store their static files in a single location either on the same server or with a third-party service.

When you define the `STATIC_URL` setting and the static files are on the same domain as the website, it's better to define it as a root-relative url, e.g. `'/static/'`. This increases portability and is less likely to cause errors. You will no longer have to worry if you have covered all systems where the code can be deployed.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Sounds like it just comes down to personal preference for the most part then?